# Unit test where the video recorded are located

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am working on a a test solution through the CodedUITest framework on visual studio 2017 enterprise.
I am using a runsettings file as detailed here : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019#example-runsettings-file

I set the mediarecorder in order to get the video even when the test passed:

```
<DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Screen and Voice Recorder">
    <!--Video data collector was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
    <Configuration>
      <!-- Set "sendRecordedMediaForPassedTestCase" to "false" to add video attachments to failed tests only -->
      <MediaRecorder sendRecordedMediaForPassedTestCase="true"  xmlns="">           
        <ScreenCaptureVideo bitRate="512" frameRate="2" quality="20" />
      </MediaRecorder>
    </Configuration>
  </DataCollector>
```

But I did not find where the video file is stored.
Any idea where I can find it? Is it possible to specify a folder path where we want to store the record?

Thx,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check further up in the runsettings file: Recordings are stored underneath the `ResultsDirectory`

```
<RunSettings>
  <RunConfiguration>
    ...
      <!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
      <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
```

Comment: Indeed... I am blind ahah ^^'